# Getting NotNullViolation when passing Data through simple_form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm getting above error when passing data through *simple_form_for*. My view, controller and database file is included below. This looks like I am not getting the values submitted by *simple_form_for* in controller. Note that, in my database table, attribute `status` is `not null` and I am not taking it as an input in view. How can I solve this error?

Database

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "team_lead_id"
t.string "name", null: false
t.string "email", null: false
t.string "password", null: false
t.date "joining_date", null: false
t.integer "status", null: false
t.integer "role"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

View

```
<%= simple_form_for @user , :url => user_createUser_url, :method => :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %><br />
    <%= f.input :email%><br />
    <%= f.input :password %><br />
    <%= f.input :joining_date, as: :date, order: [:day, :month, :year] %><br/>
    <%= f.submit "Create User" %>
  <% end %>
```

Controller

```
def createUser

    fresh = User.new

    fresh.name = params[:name]
    fresh.email = params[:email]
    fresh.password = params[:password]
    fresh.joining_date = params[:joining_date]
    fresh.status = 1
    fresh.role = 3

    if fresh.save
      flash[:notice] = "User Created"
      redirect_to(:action => index)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Creating failed"
      redirect_to(:action => index)
    end

  end
```

And I'm getting this Error

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (12, null, null, null, null, null, 1, 3, 2018-11-12 13:37:54.589835, 2018-11-12 13:37:54.589835). : INSERT INTO "users" ("status", "role", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: If you look at your logs, the form values are under `params[:user]`. So the name would be under `params[:user][:name]`. Also have a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters and consider following the CRUD convention (just `create` action, not `createUser`) and the ruby snake_case naming convention (i.e `create_user` instead of `createUser`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I'm new to rails and will follow your suggestion from my upcoming development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createUser` is not a CRUD convention, instead use `create` but also you should be using [strong parameters](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) and also don't use goofy names like `fresh` but instead model objects should be named semantically.

```
def create
  user = User.new(permitted_params)
  user.status = 1
  user.role = 3

  if user.save
    flash[:notice] = "User Created"
      redirect_to(:action => index)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Creating failed"
    redirect_to(:action => index)
  end
end

def permitted_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :joining_date)
end
```

You might not need `joining_date`, since you have `created_at`, but if you do want to keep that field, at least use the name `joined_date` or `join_date` since it will always be past tense. In fact a user is never "joining", they either have or have not "joined" yet.

As a side note you should never store passwords unencrypted, perhaps see [bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Strong parameter solved this. I'm new in rails and finding the naming convention a bit more finicky to be honest. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: The Rails guides do very good job of explaining how the framework should be used. Rails philosophy is "convention over configuration" so try to go by examples given as they are usually straight forward. The reason for naming convention goes beyond Rails. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)